# How to check and update radio-button states of two interdependent radio-groups?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, radio-button, dom-events, radio-group

In an e-shop checkout page, there are some radio buttons for choosing the shipping method. Eg.:

```
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_flat_rate1" value="flat_rate:1" class="shipping_method">
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_local_pickup2" value="local_pickup:2" class="shipping_method">
```

There are also some other radio buttons that choose the payment method. Eg.:

```
<input id="payment_method_bacs" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="bacs" data-order_button_text="">
<input id="payment_method_cop" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="cop" data-order_button_text="">
<input id="payment_method_sia" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="sia" data-order_button_text="">
```

Some shipping methods however don't go with specific payment methods, and when you choose a shipping method that doesn't go with a specific payment method, that payment method gets removed from the DOM. So if you choose a payment method, and then go back to choose a shipping method that naturally removes that payment method, the mechanism that calculates the whole thing, still thinks the payment method is the one that was removed, and fails to calculate some additional fees.

For example, if payment method was COP (cash on pickup) and then you choose DHL for for shipping method, COP gets removed from the DOM, and the first available payment method in that case is COD (cash on delivery). However the engine still thinks that COP was the checked payment method and fails to calculate additional COD fees...

How can I check, upon shipping change if the previously selected payment method still exists?

Currently I do something like this:

```
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('form.checkout').on('change', 'input.shipping_method', function() {
            console.log($('input[name=payment_method]:checked').val());
            $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
        });
    });
```

and let's say I get COP in the console, because that's what was last selected as a payment method. But as soon as the `change` event happens, and the COP `input` is removed from the DOM, I want to cause the payment method radio to change to COD. In other words, how can I check whether `<input id="payment_method_cop" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="cop" data-order_button_text="">` still exists in the DOM? But I'd like to check it using the name and the value, not its id... Something like `'input[name=payment_method]'` with value `cop`...

Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: Could the OP provide a matrix/table of supported payment methods per shipping option or vice verse, available shipping options per payment method?

Comment: Basically COP payment requires local pickup. All other combinations are valid!

Comment: Regarding the so far provided sole approach / solution are there any questions left?

Comment: Does the OP still participate in this thread?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could implement kind of a *"poor man's component approach"* which is based on [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) global attributes and an element's related [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property. Relying mainly on the data attributes allows for markup-flexibility not only for the used html-elements and `id` as well as `class` attribute-values but also structure-wise.

Each radio control could feature e.g. a `data-name` attribute with the control's distinct payment-option or shipping-method name as value and in addition an optional `data-disables` attribute where the value is a comma separated string of control names. Thus one then can implement a generic `'click'` and `'change'` handling which changes the disabled states of all of a component's radio controls according to the shipping and payment interdependencies that got provided by the component specific data attributes.

```js
// element query helper.
function getComponentStatesFromEvent(evt) {
  const target = (
    evt.target.closest('[type="radio"]') ||
    evt.target.closest('label')
  );
  const control = (target?.type === 'radio')
    ? target
    : target?.querySelector('[type="radio"]'
  );
  const root = target?.closest('[data-payment-and-shipping]');

  const shippingtNode = root?.querySelector('[data-shipping]');
  const paymentNode = root?.querySelector('[data-payment]');

  const isPayment = !!target?.closest('[data-payment]');

  return { 
    root, target, control,
    shippingtNode, paymentNode,
    isPayment,
  };
}

// enables any component's clicked but disabled radio control
// and updates all of a revivied controls interdependencies.
function reviveControlAndUpdateInterdependencies(evt) {
  const {
    control, shippingtNode,
    paymentNode, isPayment,
  } = getComponentStatesFromEvent(evt);

  if (control) {
    if (control.disabled) {

      control.disabled = false;
    }
    if (control.checked) {

      ((isPayment && paymentNode) || shippingtNode)
        .querySelectorAll('[type="radio"]')
        .forEach(elmNode =>
          (elmNode !== control) && (elmNode.disabled = false)
        );
      updatePaymentAndShippingDependencies({ target: control });
    }
  }  
}
// changes the disabled states of all of a component's radio
// controls according to shipping and payment interdependencies.
function updatePaymentAndShippingDependencies(evt) {
  const {
    control, shippingtNode,
    paymentNode, isPayment,
  } = getComponentStatesFromEvent(evt);

  if (control) {
    const disabledNames = (control.dataset.disables ?? '')
      .split(',')
      .map(str => str.trim());

    Array
      .from(
        ((isPayment && shippingtNode) || paymentNode)
          .querySelectorAll('[type="radio"]')
      )
      .forEach(elmNode =>
        elmNode.disabled = disabledNames
          .indexOf(elmNode.dataset.name ?? '') !== -1
      );
  }
}

// poor man's component approach
// based on the "data-*" global attribute.
function initPaymentAndShippingComponent() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('[data-payment-and-shipping]')
    .forEach(elmNode => {
      elmNode.addEventListener(
        'click', reviveControlAndUpdateInterdependencies
      );
      elmNode.addEventListener(
        'change', updatePaymentAndShippingDependencies
      );
    });
}
initPaymentAndShippingComponent();
```

```css
[data-payment-and-shipping] [type="radio"]:disabled + span { opacity: .4; }
```

```html
<fieldset data-payment-and-shipping>
  <legend>payment and shipping</legend>

  <!--
    Basically COP payment requires local pickup. All other combinations are valid! 
  //-->

  <fieldset class="payment_options" data-payment>
    <legend>payment options</legend>

    <label>
      <input
        type="radio" name="payment"
        value="bacs" data-name="bacs"
        data-disables="localpickup"
      />
      <span>bacs</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input
        type="radio" name="payment"
        value="cop" data-name="cop"
        data-disables="flatrate"
      />
      <span>cop</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input
        type="radio" name="payment"
        value="sia"  data-name="sia"
        data-disables="localpickup"
      />
      <span>sia</span>
    </label>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="shipping_methods" data-shipping>
    <legend>shipping methods</legend>

    <label>
      <input
        type="radio" name="shipping"
        value="flat_rate" data-name="flatrate"
        data-disables="cop"
      />
      <span>flat rate</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input
        type="radio" name="shipping"
        value="local_pickup" data-name="localpickup"
        data-disables="bacs,sia"
      />
      <span>local pickup</span>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</fieldset>
```